# Group ListView items by date has strange vehavior

Tags: android, listview

I have a chat window that has list of messages. I want to group the messages by date like whatsapp does.
My solution was to  add the header to all items and make it only visible if the item is the first item with that date and hide it else where. I get the day of the year of each message and compare but I did not get the expected behavior. Some time the list appears with the date correctly then date disappears and looks different like the image below. I think the problem is that getView is not called in order.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View row = convertView;
    MessageHolder holder = null;
    ChatMessageThread msg = data.get(position);

    int  msgData = TimingUtils.getDateFromStringTimeStamp(msg.getSendTime());



    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row                     = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder                  = new MessageHolder();
        holder.time             = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);
        holder.txtTitle         = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_messages_title);
        holder.txtDate          = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msg_date);

        row.setTag(holder);   
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (MessageHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    if (position>0 && msg.getSendTime()!=null ) {

    }



    holder.txtTitle.setText(msg.getContent());
    holder.time.setText(TimingUtils.getFormattedDate(msg.getSendTime()));
    holder.txtDate.setText(""+TimingUtils.getFormattedDate(msg.getSendTime()));

    LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.txtTitle.getLayoutParams();

    if (msg.getUserId().equals( GlobalVaribles.account.getUserId())) {

        holder.txtTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outgoing);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

    } else {

        holder.txtTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.incoming);

        lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

    }
    holder.txtTitle.setLayoutParams(lp);
    holder.time.setLayoutParams(lp);



    //first item only
    if (currentTempDate == -1) {
        currentTempDate = msgData;
        holder.txtDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        if (msgData == currentTempDate) {
            Log.i("DAY",""+msg.getContent()+ "msgData"+msgData+ "currentTempDate"+currentTempDate);

            holder.txtDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (msgData>currentTempDate) {
            holder.txtDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            currentTempDate = msgData;
        } 
    }


    return row;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the data source to get the previous item and not dependent on getView calls

```
//Current Item

        try {
            currentItem = (ChatMessageThread) getItem(position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    try {
        previousItem = (ChatMessageThread) getItem(position-1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        previousItem = null;
    }

    if (previousItem ==null) {
        previousItem = currentItem;
        holder.txtDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {

        if (TimingUtils.getDay(currentItem.getSendTime()) == 
                TimingUtils.getDay(previousItem.getSendTime())) {
            holder.txtDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else{
            holder.txtDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        previousItem = currentItem;
    }
```